# Creating heterogeneous risk score groups (risk based groups on the score)

Tags: r, sas, risk, heterogeneity, credit-scoring

I just built a credit risk score model (using logistic regression).

Now that I have all estimates and resulting score per observation I would like to create risk groups, e.g.: 10 risk groups where 1 is very low or now risk and 10 is very high risk.
I am looking for an algorithm in R (or SAS) that helps me split the resulting model score into 10 (or similar number) of heterogeneous (based on regression model target odds).

A simple example is to split population into groups where the average odds are doubled by the next group :

```
Risk 
Group               Odds    %Population
1(score 1-80)       0.8     10%
2(score 80-120)     1.6      5%
3(score 12-220)     3.2     20%
4(score 220-400)    6.4      8%
....
```

All ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered k-means clustering in one dimension? For each k, you could compute inter-cluster distance (or something similar) and see how it changes.

$$
\begin{align}
OneCluster_r &= \sum_i \sum_j || x_i - x_j || ^2\\
&= 2n_r \sum ||x_i - \bar{x}||^2\\
AllCluster_k &= \sum_{r=1}^k\frac{1}{2n_r}D_r
\end{align}
$$

As $k$ approaches 1, the $AllCluster_k$ will always increase, but there should be some large jumps when two distinct clusters are joined together. And even though k-means isn't guaranteed to find a global minimum, with one dimension and just a few clusters, this may not be a problem in this situation.

Comment: Thank you Eric, I will give it a try and see what comes. I overheard from a friend that there should be function (R or SAS) to create groups based on target (binary) odds that should be homogeneous inside and heterogeneous btw themselves. Your approach should do something similar. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your logistic regression model is named 'fit', you can create groups based on the quantile of the predicted probability using quantcut() in the gtools package as follows:

library(gtools)

dd_test$pred <- predict(fit,type='response')

dd_test$grp <- quantcut(dd_test$pred)

You can adjust the number of risk groups - just look at the quantcut() documentation and change the 'q' parameter accordingly.